# Got the right node with Nokogiri, but need to search further

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, scrape

I am using this.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
pic = doc.search "[text()*='hiRes']"
```

to get this script node:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {
'colorImages': { 'initial': 
[{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/71MBTEP1W9L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/41xE2XADIvL._US40_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/41xE2XADIvL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/71MBTEP1W9L._UX395_.jpg":[395,260],"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/71MBTEP1W9L._UX500_.jpg":[500,329],"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/71MBTEP1W9L._UX535_.jpg":[535,352],"http://ecx.images-joes.com/images
/I/71MBTEP1W9L._UX575_.jpg":[575,379]}
```

and the node keeps going from there..

But the only thing I need to pull out is the entire URL that contains the string. "UL1500" or the URL that follows "hiRes:".. ex. [http://ecx.images-joes.com/images/I/71MBTEP1W9L.*UL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-joes.com/images/I/71MBTEP1W9L._UL1500_.jpg)

I looked up the class that Nokogiri returns, and its a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

But I'm not sure how to interact with it in order to get what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went from just using Nokogiri to a regex expression.. but ended up finding this and it worked like magic!!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939906/4386626

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It's a NodeSet, because of the generic case.

See: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/master/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#children-instance_method

In this case you could try:

```
pic.children.first.content
```