# Common-sense URL extraction in Ruby

Tags: ruby, url

Consider a URL embedded in plain text, such as http://example.com/. Stack Overflow is smart enough to know that I didn't mean to include the period at the end as part of the URL, even though `.` is an unreserved character according to [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Likewise, if I type http://example.org/, Stack Overflow is smart enough to know that I didn't mean to include the comma, even though as a member of the `sub-delims` class, `,` is a valid path character.

Ruby's `URI.extract()`, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716632/27358) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939906/27358) highly-voted answer, is not as smart as Stack Overflow.

```
2.2.5 :002 > URI.extract('...such as http://example.com/.')
 => ["http://example.com/."] 
2.2.5 :003 > URI.extract('Likewise, if I type http://example.org/, Stack Overflow...')
 => ["http://example.org/,"]
```

Is there a smarter alternative?

Comment: So a URI could potentially contain both `,` and `.` which is probably why `extract` includes them. If you were looking to customize the behavior you could pass extract a block and then maybe check against the extracted string to see if it has any values that you would consider invalid.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract-label-Synopsis
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url

It is annoying that you even have to consider doing anything weird here though

Comment: Yeah, I read the RFC. I'm more looking for somebody who's already thought through the common-sense use cases, so I'm not playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: I don't know but +1 on the question. I'm sure there's a well thought out regex that will solve the problem in combination with `URI.extract(..., &block)`. I haven't thought it out very well though